# Possible? Android Permission Request Concurrency Issue

Tags: java, android

Is there a possibility that the below code could fail due to the user denying the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission after the permissions check and before the alarm is scheduled?

Note: I have never experienced this issue, this is purely an academic excersize.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private void scheduleExactAlarm(Calendar alarmCalendar) {

        if(getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // handle permission not granted
            return;
        }

        // can the user deny the permission here?

        AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmInfo = // create alarmInfo with desired information
        PendingIntent alarmOperation = // create alarmOperation with desired intent    
        AlarmManager alarmManager = getSystemService(AlarmManager.class);    
        alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmInfo, alarmOperation);
    }
    
    // the rest of the service implementation...

}
```

EDIT: I learned something new today. Special Permissions are not part of runtime permissions, so using `checkSelfPermission(SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM)` doesn't make sense. That being said, the question is intended to be broader than the specific permissions/operations used.

Comment: `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` is not a dangerous permission, so it can never be denied or revoked. Is there a reason you are checking to see if you have that permission at runtime at all?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I should have given more context. I am targetting API level 32 so SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM is required to schedule exact alarms and can be revoked in Special App Access, per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#exact-permission-check). However, the intent of the question is not about the specific permission and/or operation, but rather if there theoretically exists a race condition between checking a permission and executing an operation that requires it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Android will terminate your process if Android revokes a permission for any reason (user revoked it in Settings, auto-revocation due to lack of app use on Android 12+, etc.).

That being said, Ian Lake's comment is also valid: `checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM)` <strike>should never return `PERMISSION_GRANTED`</strike> is not going to work well. While your concern is valid for `dangerous` permissions, based on current 13 DP1 behavior, `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM` is not categorized as `dangerous` and is not part of the runtime permission system.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#one-time) and testing on an emulator, revoking a permission results in Android terminating the app's proccesses and restarting them. Because a race condition cannot occur if there is no process to run, I'm marking your answer as the correct one.

Comment: I'd also like to note that while testing on the emulator, `checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM)` returned 0 (regardless of whether the permission was toggled on/off in special app access) which also happens to be the same value as PERMISSION_GRANTED. I don't know if that is intended behavior or not.

Comment: @pogo_sticks1011: I updated my answer, and I apologize for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically?  Sure, if the OS decided to task switch taking the processor away from the app, and the user denied permission before it task switched back.  Practically?  No, task switches happen many times a second, there's no way it wouldn't get a time slice before a user would do that.

Comment: That is what I thought. But the idea that it pratically would never occur seems off to me. For an average user, there may be a few background services running at any given time performing operations that require revokable permissions and jobs executed by JobScheduler and WorkManager doing the same. Is it reasonable to be concerned about this? In particular, is it worth taking a hint from python and "Ask forgiveness, not permission"?

Comment: @pogo_sticks1011 I interpreted your question as being about the time between the permission check and the call to schedule the alarm.  If you mean the alarm going off-  then yes, that's very possible.  Since permissions for alarms are a new thing, I'm not sure if work scheduled but not yet executed would still go off or not.  I would assume no, but it would be an easy bug to have happen (just forget to check permissions again on firing the alarm and only check on scheduling them).

Comment: Your original interpretation was correct. I was talking about the time between the permission check and the call to schedule alarm. In my previous comment, I was trying convey that it seems possible for the race condition to occur in practice, due to the fact that many processes/jobs could be running in the background at one, increasing the likelihood. However as CommonsWare pointed out, that wouldn't occur anyway due to the Android terminating the process.

Comment: True, but lets ignore CommosWare (correct) point.  It could happen, but in normal use the time difference between point A and point B is microseconds.  You'd need to be very unlucky to even lose the processor.  So it *could* happen, but if it does, buy a lotto ticket.

Comment: But point A and point B involves more than just 2 machine instructions. One of the things I omitted in the code is the creation of the alarmInfo and alarmOperation objects, which in itself could be a lot of code. Also, the call to getSystemService (I'm assuming) requires IPC which is typical point the OS switches to a different process. All  considered it is concievable that the delay between "point A and point B" is more than a  few milliseconds. Then if one considers that several background processes could be doing this at once, its imaginable that a race condition could occur in pratice

Comment: @pogo_sticks1011 You can't change the game by saying "well I ommitted extra stuff".   But at any rate you're still talking 10s to 100s of microseconds, a few allocations is not that slow.  And getSystemService doesn't require IPC generally. Making requests on the service does, but the reference itself doesn't need to. So yes, it could happen theoretically.  No, its highly unlikely it ever would.  And besides which, you're now talking about several theoretical background services when not even one exists-  there is no process that goes around randomly revoking permissions.